# is there a way to get codeigniter to create a plain text page where \n char works properly?

Tags: codeigniter

I am trying to use vanilla forum with proxyconnect and it requires i give it a plain text file of my user's authentication cookie values in the form below.  However, when i send it the only way i can get it to work is with the 
 tags and i needs to have the \n tag.

document should be:

```
UniqueID=5
Name=Kyle
Email=email@email.com
```

I can get it to display like that with br tags but when i use \n tags they show up like this:

```
UniqueID=5\nName=Kyle\nEmail=email@email.com
```

here is the method in the controller

```
function get_user_info(){
  if(!empty($this->user)){
   printf('UniqueID=' . $this->user['userID'] . '\n');
   printf('Name=' . $this->user['userFirst'] . '\n');
   printf('Email=' . $this->user['userEmail'] . '\n');
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use use "\n" with double quotes instead. Special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Example

```
printf('Name=' . $this->user['userFirst'] . "\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

Along with what rkj has suggested above, you need to output the page as plain text. To do this, add this to the beginning of your controller's function:

```
$this->output->set_header("Content-Type: text/plain");
```